# Redirect to Subdir and preserve query string as is as part of filename

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have to redirect a domain to a subfolder using .htaccess. I have done this with

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^domain\.de/ /domain.de%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This works for 90% of my site.

But I also have file reference like:

`domain.de/templates/shaper_helix3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2%3Fv=4.3.0.html`

The file exists in the filesystem with the filename:
`fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0.html` (including query string)

These files are currently not found (404).
If I manually remove the query string from the filename (e.g. resulting in `fontawesome-webfont.woff2`) I get a HTTP Code 200 (Found).

I have multiple files with said filename structure and can not "hardcode" them, because through updates and installation of additional modules via CMS I can not know, which files will exist in the future in the respective directories.

The reason for the files inlcuding a Query String / version in their names is cache busting.

How do I have to modify my rules, so that these files can also be found?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess rules. These rules are for internal rewrite ones.

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(templates/shaper_helix3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont\.woff2)%3F(v=4\.3\.0\.html)/?$ $1?$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

***OR*** if it could be any file under `templates/shaper_helix3/fonts/fontawesomefont/` then try following:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(templates/shaper_helix3/fonts/[^%]*)%3F(v=4\.3\.0\.html)/?$ $1?$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: This one was just a sample. I have multiple files (JS, CSS, ...) with said filename structure. I need a generic solution for this problem, because there can be more / other files in the future through updates of CMS components.

Comment: @Raphael, oh ok then could you please common url by which I can write a regex to catch things and then use it for common reules etc.

Comment: @Raphael, OR please try my OR rules once and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$ [NC]
> RewriteRule !^domain\.de/ /domain.de%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
> ```

The "problem" here is that the `REQUEST_URI` server variable is already %-decoded so ends up rewriting a request for `/fontawesome-webfont.woff2%3Fv=4.3.0.html` to `/domain.de/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?Fv=4.3.0.html` (ie. a file `fontawesome-webfont.woff2` with a query string of `v=4.3.0.html`, not a literal file called `fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0.html`). You need to maintain the %-encoding through the rewrite so `%3F` is rewritten to `%3F`, ie. `/domain.de/fontawesome-webfont.woff2%3Fv=4.3.0.html` (which is later decoded when the request is finally mapped to the filesystem), not `?` (that delimits an actual query string).

You can do this by capturing the URL-path with a backreference (also %-decoded) but use the `B` flag that re-encodes the backreference before rewriting the request.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain\.de/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) domain.de/$1 [B,L]
```